# CSS compatibility check for multiple browsers?

Tags: css

Is there an online tool that would take a CSS file and tell me which parts are incompatible with which browser?

Ex: property-a -> ff 3.0+, ie7+, etc
property-b-> ff 2.0, ie5...

Comment: i dont believe such tool exists, but it should!

Comment: It should be line by line or even property by property. Because a result like: This CSS file is not supported in IE7 could be wrong in most cases